# chain substitute() in R

Tags: r

I am trying to get names in a list twice passed in function calls, such as :

```
fn1 <- function(arg1){
    a<-substitute(arg1)
    print(a)
}
fn2 <- function(arg2){
    fn1(arg2[[2]])
}  
fn2(list(list(sum,sum,min),list(min,min,sum)))
```

And would like the print to display

```
list(min,min,sum)
```

I am trying combinations of `eval()` and `substitute()` but can't get it right.

Comment: use deparse() function with substitute

Comment: @akrun, it works in itself but is not usable in my case as the argument is used in both fn1 and fn2

Comment: @VikramnathVenkatasubramani sure but how to use deparse?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this may help

```
fn1 <- function(...) {
      lapply(substitute(...)[-1], deparse)
     }

fn2 <- function(...){
  fn1(...)[[2]]
}

fn2(list(list(sum,sum,min),list(min,min,sum)))
#[1] "list(min, min, sum)"
```

Answer (score 1):

fn2 can remain same, use this as fn1

```
 fn1 <- function(arg1){
    print(deparse(arg1[[2]]))
 }
```

but call the function using quote() around the function names min,sum,etc

```
fn2(list(list(quote(sum),quote(sum),quote(min)),
       list(quote(min),quote(min),quote(sum))))
```

Output

```
fn2(list(list(quote(sum),quote(sum),quote(min)),list(quote(min),quote(min),quote(sum))))
[1] "list(min, min, sum)"
```

Answer (score 0):

#### An imperfect solution

Seems like there are no fn1-change only answers. This is what I prefer (smaller modifification to the fn2 call) but I don't accept it as it doesn't really allows to chain substitute calls:

```
fn1 <- function(arg1){
    print(arg1)
}
fn2 <- function(arg2){
    fn1(arg2[[3]])
}
fn2(quote(c(list(sum,sum,min),list(min,min,sum))))
```

#### Explanation

The key is to pass a quoted expression to fn2, this prevents evaluation of the string:

```
fn2(quote(list(list(sum,sum,min),list(min,min,sum))))
```

As the call is quoted, the first item is `list` , the second is `list(sum,sum,min)`, the third is ̀`list(min,min,sum)`. I then pass `arg2[[3]]` to fn1:

```
fn2 <- function(arg2){
    fn1(arg2[[3]])
}
```

And printing is obvious in fn1:

```
fn1 <- function(arg1){
    print(arg1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer ***not implying a modification of the fn2 call***, inspired by heavy reading of [Hadley's course](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#calling-from-another-function)

As `substitute()` can only be called one level up from the call, define two functions:

```
fn1_q <- function(arg1){
    print(arg1)
}
fn1 <- function(arg1){
    fn1_q(substitute(arg1))
}
fn2 <- function(arg2){
    exprArg2 <- substitute(arg2)
    fn1_q(exprArg2[[3]])
}
> fn2(list(list(sum,sum,min),list(min,min,sum)))
list(min, min, sum)
> 
> fn1(list(min,min,sum))
list(min, min, sum)
```